# I dont see Django profile update form in my templates

Tags: python, django

I am using Django. And the problems are with user profile update form, it seems like I have been doing everything right, but I cant see the update form in my generated HTML template. In form I see the submit button and because of that think that the problem is not from HTML file. And here are my files!

**Django Template (partial)**

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        window.location.href = "{% url 'main' %}";
    }
</script>
{% else %}
<h3>I am {{ user.username }}</h3>

<img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" width="300">
{% endif %}

<!-- User Update Forms -->
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ u_form|crispy }}
    {{ p_form|crispy }}

    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

**update form in forms.py**

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name  = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=30)

    def supervalid(self):
        expr_a = User.objects.filter(first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name']).exists()
        expr_b = User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists()

        if expr_b:
            raise ValidationError(f'There already exists user with that email, use another one ;)')

        if expr_a:
            raise ValidationError(f'This name is already used, sorry')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('self')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'self/index.html', context)
```

**And finally models**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile @{self.user.username}'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**Rendered HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Joshua - BareTalk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>I am Joshua</h3>
    <img src="/media/default.png" width="300">
    <!-- User Update Forms -->
    <form
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
      <input
        type="hidden"
        name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
        value="PINgIhf5ieFoe2HSIOXprpxpsSuhZhuxuKbxBRCVHGwq40XAQIEASnJKaSE26ItU"
      >
      <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show resulting HTML?

Comment: do you mean to screenshot?

Comment: no, just html code you get in your browser

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Joshua - BareTalk</title>
</head>
<body>


<h3>I am Joshua</h3>

<img src="/media/default.png" width="300">


<!-- User Update Forms -->
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="PINgIhf5ieFoe2HSIOXprpxpsSuhZhuxuKbxBRCVHGwq40XAQIEASnJKaSE26ItU">
 



 




 <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Could you update your question with that? As I see - both forms are not rendered.

Comment: can u plz help with code?

Comment: Do you have `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` in your template?

Comment: yes I do.........

Comment: And I think you should remove remove `u_form` and `p_form` assignment in the view (that one before context declaration).

Comment: I tried to remove, it doesnt helped

Comment: Can't reproduce. The only way to reproduce this is if the two variables are either None or not passed to the template. So you're most likely looking at the wrong view. So what's in your urls.py and what url are you requesting?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect [Django Crispy Forms framework](https://pypi.org/project/django-crispy-forms/) cannot find a `FormHelper` attached to the form, `UserUpdateForm`. Try attaching a `FormHelper` instance to the form, `UserUpdateForm`, following [Crispy documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html).

Answer (score -1):

I guess these lines were for debug?

```
    u_form = UserUpdateForm()
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm()
```

what if you try it without crispy ?

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon and `{{ u_form.email }} also doesnt work ?

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon in the template, try to change `{{ u_form }}` to `{{ u_form.email }}`, that should render the email input.
Also, can you post from setting.py TEMPLATES a INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon if it doesnt render even the field, then the last things I can think of are:
1) try to add 'django.forms' in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS, although I dont think it's necessary to have it there, but you might try...
2) you have error in your settings.TEMPLATES...
3) check the html files in `/pythonX.X/site-packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets` if they are not empty and also check the files and the whole path if they have the right access rights